# Is it possible to create a texture only in Fragment shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, shader

I have a 2 pass rendering pipeline - Deferred shading - for point cloud rendering. (GLSL 4.30 & c++17)

**Shader pipeline:**

Pointloud.vertex --> Pointcloud.fragment --> FullscreenQuad.vertex --> Deferred.fragment

What I want to achieve is to gather some data from *Pointloud.vertex --> Pointcloud.fragment* state and as a texture send it into Deferred.fragment shader.

**Datas like:**
Vertex_ID, Frag-Coord.z and texture coordinates (availible in Pointloud.vertex part )

Basically I want to create 2 texture in Pointcloud.fragment shader,on the given texture coord position store the dept information and in the another texture store the vertex ID on the same coords.

Is it possible to create and write into textures locally in shaders? Important is to solve this without c++ impact.

Comment: _"Important is to solve this without c++ impact."_ Could you elaborate about this requirement please?

Comment: `Is it possible to create and write into textures locally in shaders?` Write to: Yes. Create: no. Look up how to bind and render to multiple render-targets.

Comment: You have to render to a [Framebuffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) and to attach a [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture) to the color plane of the framsbuffer. See [Framebuffer Object - Attaching Images](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Attaching_Images).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ it is a complex application which is working perfectly, I just need to calculate something, and all the data I need are already in shaders. Moreover, I dont have access to the renderer functionality to manually attach another texture as Rabbid76 suggested. But I think if texture creation locally is not possible, this is not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shaders cannot allocate resources like textures and buffers. They can *use* resources, but they cannot create them ex nihilo. You have to create any such resources in the application. If you don't have the ability to modify the application's code, then there's nothing to be done.